# Creating model using provided json string

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I want to create models using following json string in Spring Boot.

```
{
  "name": "inox",
  "seatInfo": {
    "A": {
      "numberOfSeats": 10,
      "aisleSeats": [
        0,
        5,
        6,
        9
      ]
    },
    "B": {
      "numberOfSeats": 15,
      "aisleSeats": [
        0,
        5,
        6,
        9
      ]
    },
    "D": {
      "numberOfSeats": 20,
      "aisleSeats": [
        0,
        5,
        6,
        9
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have did this so far.

```
 import java.util.Map;
 import javax.persistence.*;

 @Entity
 public class Screen {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private Map<String, RowInfo> seatInfo;

     //getter and setters
 }


 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import java.util.Arrays;

 @Entity
 public class RowInfo {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
     private int numberOfSeats;
     private Integer aisleSeats[];

     //getters and setters
 }
```

I am getting following exception when application boots.

nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: screen, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(seat_info)]

Comment: Maybe not relevant but why mix `int` and `Integer` in the same entity declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Change Map interface with HashMap type (or a type that you prefer).

```
@Entity
public class Screen {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private HashMap<String, RowInfo> seatInfo;

     //getter and setters
 }


 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import java.util.Arrays;

 @Entity
 public class RowInfo {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
     private int numberOfSeats;
     private Integer aisleSeats[];

     //getters and setters
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA 2 then add:

```
@ElementCollection

private Map<String, RowInfo> seatInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some JPA 2 implementation: it adds a @ElementCollection annotation, similar to the Hibernate one, that does exactly what you need..

```
@Entity
public class Screen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, RowInfo> seatInfo;
}
```